# How to reference parent in inline creation of objects?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a parent/child-relationship ob objects and try to create a parent object inline (I'm not really sure that's the right word). Is it possible to reference the created parent in its own creation code?

```
Parent = new Parent(
{
    Name = "Parent",
    Child= new Child(/*ReferenceToParent*/)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way round this would be for the `Parent` constructor to call the `Child` constructor itself and pass in `this`. Your object initializer (which is what I assume you're trying to do) could then set other properties on the child:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        Child = new Child(this);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    private readonly Parent parent;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Parent parent = new Parent
{
    Name = "Parent name",
    // Sets the Name property on the existing Child
    Child = { Name = "Child name" }
};
```

I would *try* to avoid this sort of relationship though - it can get increasingly tricky as time goes on.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on the "tricky part"? I was under the impression that the garbage collector handles such circular object references just fine. I could imagine a problem with serialization but I don't plan to use any here.

Comment: @Amenti: The garbage collector is fine, but "leaking" references to `this` within your own constructor is generally a bad idea... if the `Child` constructor tries to call anything on its parent within *its* constructor, it'll be operating on a not-completely-initialized object. That could be the cause of subtle, hard-to-track bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because an instance of Parent has not been created yet. If child requires an instance of Parent in it's constructor you must create one.
Create an instance of Parent first, then Child passing in the parent to the Constructor, and then assign the instance of child to the property on Parent.

```
var parent = new Parent
{
  Name = "Parent",
  //More here...
};
var child = new Child(parent);
parent.Child = child;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because the reference starts referencing the allocated object *after* the constructor's execution has finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old and it looks there is no new solution for this in newer C# version, does it? If so, please, share.

Meanwhile, I would like to add another solution kind of similar to the accepted one, but different. It assumes that you can change the Parent class.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Parent p = new Parent()
        {
            Name = "Parent",
            Child = new Child()
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine(p.Child.Parent.Name);
    }
        
    public class Parent
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        
        public Child Child {
            get { return this._child; }
            set { 
                this._child = value; 
                if(value != null) 
                    value.Parent = this;
            }
        }
        private Child _child;
    }
    
    public class Child 
    {
        public Parent Parent {get; set;}
    }  
}
```

It can be executed in [this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEzfJm).