# How to reference parent in PowerShell script property

Tags: powershell

Given a nested PowerShell custom object like this:

```
$O = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
 ParentValue = 100
 ChildValueArray = @(
   [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'First';  Value = 1 },
   [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'Second'; Value = 2 }

 )}
```

I would like to add a script property to each of the objects in "ChildArray" that references the value "ParentValue" in the enclosing object.  Conceptually I would like to do the following:

```
$O.ChildValueArray |  Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Diff -Value { $this.Value + $parent.ParentValue }
```

However there is no $parent equivalent to $this that I can find.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour so that the result of:

```
$O.ChildValueArray | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Is:

```
Name   Value Diff
----   ----- ----
First      1    101
Second     2    102
```

Instead of the current value:

```
Name   Value Diff
----   ----- ----
First      1    1
Second     2    2
```

I suspect this is not possible for reasons outlined here:

[How to reference parent in inline creation of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843923/how-to-reference-parent-in-inline-creation-of-objects)

Comment: Why can't you simply use `$O.ParentValue`?

Comment: I can!  This was a complete brain freeze on my part.  The original formulation of the problem had me define the child before the parent - which meant I couldn't without then using Add-Member on the child to reference the parent.  There should be a "Duh!" badge - you get it for asking a blunder question!  Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me:

```
$parent = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
 ParentValue = 100
 ChildValueArray = @(
   [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'First';  Value = 1; },
   [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'Second'; Value = 2; }
 )}

 $parent.ChildValueArray `
 | % { 
    Add-Member `
        -InputObject $_ `
        -MemberType ScriptProperty `
        -Name Diff `
        -Value { $this.Value + $parent.ParentValue } }
```

Testing it yields the behavior I would expect:

```
$parent.ChildValueArray | ft *

$parent.ParentValue = 200
$parent.ChildValueArray | ft *

$parent.ChildValueArray[0].Value = 100
$parent.ChildValueArray | ft *
```

Output:

```
Name   Value Diff
----   ----- ----
First      1  101
Second     2  102

Name   Value Diff
----   ----- ----
First      1  201
Second     2  202

Name   Value Diff
----   ----- ----
First    100  300
Second     2  202
```

## Update

Actually, after further testing I can see that the `For-Each` is unnecessary.  Your code works fine if you simply replace `$parent` with `$O` in the `Add-Member` command.  Is their any reason you need to reference the parent relative to the child rather than simply specifying the parent in absolute terms?  Unless you plan an reassigning a child to a new parent you should not run into any issues using this approach.